# Any contemporary supporter Hartmann's vitalizm?

Tags: german-philosophy, intentionality, teleology

Eduard von Hartmann's view of vitalizm follows a little twist of Schelling’s combination of vitalizm and mechanism. I like his approach for vitalizm view of evolution theory, and it's interesting to me if there's any contemporary philosopher/scientist that follows this line of thought? Is there maybe a school of thought based on it?

Comment: @Gordon I just want to state, as I'm not familiar with Eros and Thanatos, I'm talking about Karl Robert Eduard von Hartmann, the author of Philosophy of the Unconscious. Any chance we're not talking about the same philosopher?

Comment: I think we are talking about the same philosopher. Well it appears he had an influence on Sabina Spielrein, and maybe from her back to Freud. Anyway, he obviously influenced Freud, at least it seems so to me.  I would have to study this more. I have an idea who he influenced but I don't want to say until I study him more.

Comment: Wikipedia has a [brief piece](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Robert_Eduard_von_Hartmann#Reception) on his reception. He influenced Schopenhauer and Freud, but I doubt he has a following, his philosophy was seen as incoherent by contemporaries as different as Husserl and Nietzsche. Bergson's [vitalistic view of evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Evolution_(book)) was far more influential and overshadowed earlier attempts.

Comment: I must correct myself. Hartmann did not influence Schopenhauer (he was 18 when Schopenhauer died), he was rather a conduit of Schopenhauer's influence on Freud. Instead of broad metaphysical strokes Hartmann focused on how the Will manifests in people psychologically, as the Unconscious, and he rhetorically distinguished this Unconscious from the more run of the mill sub/non conscious that was frequently talked about. This became Freud's point of departure and after his adoption of the idea it turned into what Hartmann is best known for today.

Comment: The key was when Spielrein developed the idea of the death instinct probably from inspiration from reading Hartmann. Freud was already aware of Hartmann, but this work of Spielrein was the missing piece that Freud needed. From this came his "Civilization and its Discontents" one of the most important essays of the last century.

Comment: "Not only can we never get what we really want,  but it is only because we cannot ever get it that we have anything at all." [Thomas Parisi]. It is after comprehending this quote that we can read Marcuse, Eros and Civilization for his possible solution.

Comment: The death drive:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_drive  See von Hartmann Wikipedia:  "Nevertheless, it must be characterized as the best possible world, for both nature and history are constantly developing in the manner best adapted to the ending of the world; and by means of increasing consciousness the idea, instead of prolonging suffering to eternity, provides a refuge from the evils of existence in non-existence.[3]"

Comment: This is essentially tension reduction, return to the womb (sex) or death ( we were not conscious in the womb). So this is a vitalism but a very sophisticated one, and before its time.

Comment: @Gordon thanks! So, can we essentially say Freudians follow Hartmann's vitalizm?

Comment: Hmmm. It may be possible to say that. Essentially we contain the vitalism and the result is Civilization. There is vitalism of course in Eros (sex, self-preservation) but also in the death instinct too when it is directed outward, and when so directed it is aggression. Sex and aggression. However, the death instinct, directed inward, can short-circuit into immediate tension reduction and release: suicide or apocalyptic thoughts. This will give a very sophisticated type of vitalism. It can be pacified possibly...see Marcuse above.

Comment: Marcuse's key problem in Eros and Civilization was that once man realized that he produced enough already, he could then have fun. BUT then there would also be less need for outward aggression, and THEN aggression could turn inward. So he had to contend with this in his book and try to solve this problem.

Comment: I should say above in a short answer to your question: yes. We know Freud had read Hartmann, he had already been influenced by him. And then Sabina Spielrein had also studied Hartmann. She put together the key piece. See Destruction Paper:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabina_Spielrein

Comment: Cite: 
Jung and his medical student
In 1905 Sabina writes to mother: “To-morrow I am going to the medical library and will borrow [Eduard von] Hartmann’s “[Philosophy of] The Unconscious”, which I accidentally saw in the catalog. Since I saw this book at Junga’s [pet name], I believe it is worth reading..." Lothane

Comment: "The real story of Sabina Spielrein: or fantasies vs. facts of a life" by
Henry Zvi Lothane, MD available PDF on the internet.  This has been a good question Yechiam, thank you.  I have learned from it.

Comment: @Gordon wow, thanks for all of this information. That helps a lot.